# Javascript - process array in batches AND show progress

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Dear Javascript Guru's:

I have the following requirements:

1. Process a large array in batches of 1000 (or any arbitrary size).
2. When each batch is processed, update the UI to show our progress.
3. When all batches have been processed, continue with the next step.

For example:

```
function process_array(batch_size) {

   var da_len = data_array.length;

   var idx = 0;


   function process_batch() {

      var idx_end = Math.min(da_len, idx + batch_size);

      while (idx < idx_end) {

         // do the voodoo we need to do

      }

   }

   // This loop kills the browser ...

   while (idx < da_len) {

      setTimeout(process_batch, 10);

      // Show some progress (no luck) ...

      show_progress(idx);

   }

}

// Process array ...

process_array(1000);

// Continue with next task ...
// BUT NOT UNTIL WE HAVE FINISHED PROCESSING THE ARRAY!!!
```

Since I am new to javascript, I discovered that everything is done on a single thread and as such, one needs to get a little creative with regard to processing and updating the UI.  I have found some examples using recursive setTimeout calls, (one key difference is I have to wait until the array has been fully processed before continuing), but I cannot seem to get things working as described above.

Also -- I am in need of a "pure" javascript solution -- no third party libraries or the use of web workers (that are not fully supported).

Any (and all) guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank-you all for your comments and suggestions.

Below is a code that I settled on.  The code works for any task (in my case, processing an array) and gives the browser time to update the UI if need be.

The "do_task" function starts an anonymous function via setInterval that alternates between two steps -- processing the array in batches and showing the progress, this continues until all elements in the array have been processed.

```
  function do_task() {

     const k_task_process_array = 1;

     const k_task_show_progress = 2;


     var working = false;

     var task_step = k_task_process_array;

     var batch_size = 1000;

     var idx = 0;

     var idx_end = 0;

     var da_len = data_array.length;


     // Start the task ...

     var task_id = setInterval(function () {

        if (!working) {

           working = true;

           switch (task_step) {

              case k_task_process_array:

                 idx_end = Math.min( idx + batch_size, da_len );

                 while (idx < idx_end) {

                    // do the voodoo we need to do ...

                    }

                    idx++;

                 }

                 task_step = k_task_show_progress;

                 working = false;

                 break;

              default:

                 // Show progress here ...


                 // Continue processing array ...

                 task_step = k_task_process_array;

                 working = false;

           }


           // Check if done ...

           if (idx >= da_len) {

              clearInterval(task_id);

              task_id = null;

           }

           working = false;

        }

     }, 1);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stream from array and use batch-stream to make batches so that you can stream in batches to UI.

[stream-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-array)

and

[batch-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/batch-stream)

Comment: Interesting, but this solution could work for node.js, I think OP need a solution for the browser instead.

Comment: One can always browserify node-modules and I thought making stream would improve performance so suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript when executing scripts in a HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive until the script is finished. This is because JavaScript is single thread.

You could consider using a web worker in JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page.

In this case User can continue to do whatever he wants in the UI.

You can send and receive messages from the web worker.

[More info on Web Worker here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: You couldn't track progress, because the worker would be thread-locked. You would just be notified when it was done.

Comment: @Norguard thanks for commenting, Web Worker can send message to the main UI thread. Depending of the design, progress or other status could communicated and shown to the user IMO.

Comment: It can. What I mean to say is if it's just going to process the whole array, because now you're in a webworker, when is it going to stop to show progress?

Comment: @Norguard, it doesn't have to stop, since you are on a parallel thread : https://jsfiddle.net/k52x12eu/

Comment: Right. I haven't thought in accumulators in a while. I was busy thinking `wholeArray.map(transform)`, which becomes possible once you unblock the primary thread; because unblocking the thread was the point of moving it to the worker to begin with.

Comment: @Norguard Please do not forget to accept or upvote my answer if you found it useful :) thanks ans happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

So part of the magic of recursion is really thinking about the things that you need to pass in, to make it work.

And in JS (and other functional languages) that frequently involves functions.

```
function processBatch (remaining, processed, batchSize,
                       transform, onComplete, onProgress) {
  if (!remaining.length) {
    return onComplete(processed);
  }
  const batch = remaining.slice(0, batchSize);
  const tail = remaining.slice(batchSize);

  const totalProcessed = processed.concat(batch.map(transform));
  return scheduleBatch(tail, totalProcessed, batchSize,
                       transform, onComplete, onProgress);
}

function scheduleBatch (remaining, processed, batchSize,
                        transform, onComplete, onProgress) {
  onProgress(processed, remaining, batchSize);
  setTimeout(() => processBatch(remaining, processed, batchSize,
                                transform, onComplete, onProgress));
}

const noop = () => {};
const identity = x => x;

function processArray (array, batchSize, transform, onComplete, onProgress) {
  scheduleBatch(
    array,
    [],
    batchSize,
    transform || identity,
    onComplete || noop,
    onProgress || noop
  );
}
```

This can be simplified extremely, and the reality is that I'm just having a little fun here, but if you follow the trail, you should see recursion in a closed system that works with an arbitrary transform, on arbitrary objects, of arbitrary array lengths, with arbitrary code-execution when complete, and when each batch is completed and scheduling the next run.

To be honest, you could even swap this implementation out for a custom scheduler, by changing 3 lines of code or so, and then you could log whatever you wanted...

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const batchSize = 2;
const showWhenDone = numbers => console.log(`Done with: ${numbers}`);
const showProgress = (processed, remaining) =>
  `${processed.length} done; ${remaining.length} to go`;

const quintuple = x => x * 5;

processArray(
  numbers,
  batchSize,
  quintuple,
  showWhenDone,
  showProgress
);

// 0 done; 6 to go
// 2 done; 4 to go
// 4 done; 2 to go
// Done with: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
```

Overkill? Oh yes. But worth familiarizing yourself with the concepts, if you're going to spend some time in the language.